# I am not able to generate hibernate.reveng.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, reverse-engineering

I am trying to develop Spring Hibernate Application from Some tutorial, where I found that, for Hibernate configuration, There should be also `hibernate.reveng.xml` inside config folder.

But When I'm trying to create it by `Right Click Project > New > Hibernate...`
Here,I didn't find `Hibernate` under the `New` dialogue box.

Is there another way to create `hibernate.reveng.xml`?

---

Sorry, if i'm improper in asking question. But it's my first question on stackoverflow. :)

Comment: There's some typos in your question, I'd recommend fixing those!

Comment: Well,I'm using Eclipse LUNA for developing Application

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Create Hibernate entites from exisiting db using Hibernate-Tools?

Comment: Ya @Manza  I'm trying to insert data in mysql db table through application as i'm developing simple CRUD app to understand basic flow of SPRING HIBERNATE .project

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ ya I correct it! plz tel me if u have any idea about this problem. Thanx.

Comment: @neer: I'm no expert at your problem, but it really hurts my willingness to read a question if it has a lot of avoidable mistakes (no problem if your English isn't perfect -- I'm no native speaker, either), and my enthusiasm definitely vanishes  if people don't have the time to write "you" instead of "u", "plz" instead of a nice word, "ya" instead of addressing a person, and "thanx" to look cool. Grow up, verbally, if you want a hint on how to get better answers and be met at eye level.

Comment: Hello, @MarcusMüller , You are right, I should be more proper when I am writing to Communities like SO. Thanks!